# System.PlatformNotSupported Exception, no recognizer installed

Tags: c#, speech

I'm making a program where I need speech recognition engine, but I ran into the problem that says "no recognizer installed". I've been searching for 2 days, what can i do about it, but found nothing useful. I red nearly all of the other question, here, who struggled with this similar problem, but links are outdated. I tried things like looking ofr installed recognizors but got nothing installed. I tried to figure out whats the difference between `Microsoft.Speech` and `System.Speech`, didnt get to far Here is my code, what am i missing?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace Essex
{
    public partial class Essex : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        
        public Essex()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Choices commands = new Choices();
            commands.Add(new string[] { "say hello", "print my name" });
            GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
            gBuilder.Append(commands);
            Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

            recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
            recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            recEngine.SpeechRecognized += RecEngine_SpeechRecognized;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void RecEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Result.Text)
            {
                case "say hello":
                    label1.Text = "Welcome sir";
                    break;
                case "print my name":
                    label1.Text = "John Smith";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: visual studio 2019? if thats the answer

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: Windows 10 20H2 version

Comment: Still haven't found solution